# Remove spacing within text block

Tags: sections-paragraphs

In my MWE below, I am using `\parskip = \baselineskip` but wanted to remove the following spacings:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\parskip = \baselineskip

\begin{document}
\chapter{Problems from Chapter 9}

\section{Problem 9-3}\index{Problem 9-3}

\subsection{Problem 9-3}
(Sorenson, 1980, Exercise 3-15, p. 130).  Suppose $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are unbiased estimators of $\theta$ with var$(\theta_{1}) = \sigma_{1}^{2}$ and var$(\theta_{2}) = \sigma_{2}^{2}$.  Let $\theta_{3} = \alpha\theta_{1} + (1-\alpha)\theta_{2}$.
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,style=nextline,leftmargin=*,labelsep=\parindent,label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
\item Prove that $\theta_{3}$ is unbiased.
\item Assume that $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are statically independent, and find the measured squared error of $\theta_{3}$.
\item What choice of $\alpha$ minimizes the mean-squared error?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How can remove the indicated spacings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is a sub section and hence you can load `titlesec` package and use its `titlespacing*` macro

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{-10pt}
```

The third argument is the space after (below) the title which I have made `-10pt`. Adjust as you wish.

For the second space, you can apply the original `\parskip` value (i. e., `0pt plus 1pt`) only for the `enumerate` by

```
before=\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1pt},align=left,....
```

in the options.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\parskip = \baselineskip


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{-10pt}




\begin{document}
\chapter{Problems from Chapter 9}

\section{Problem 9-3}\index{Problem 9-3}
\subsection{Problem 9-3}
(Sorenson, 1980, Exercise 3-15, p. 130).  Suppose $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are unbiased estimators of $\theta$ with var$(\theta_{1}) = \sigma_{1}^{2}$ and var$(\theta_{2}) = \sigma_{2}^{2}$.  Let $\theta_{3} = \alpha\theta_{1} + (1-\alpha)\theta_{2}$.
%
\begin{enumerate}[before=\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1pt},align=left,style=nextline,leftmargin=*, labelsep=\parindent,label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
\item Prove that $\theta_{3}$ is unbiased.
\item Assume that $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are statically independent, and find the measured squared error of $\theta_{3}$.
\item What choice of $\alpha$ minimizes the mean-squared error?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Instead of adjusting `\parskip` yourself, you may use `parskip` package which gives better spacing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Problems from Chapter 9}

\section{Problem 9-3}\index{Problem 9-3}
\subsection{Problem 9-3}
(Sorenson, 1980, Exercise 3-15, p. 130).  Suppose $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are unbiased estimators of $\theta$ with var$(\theta_{1}) = \sigma_{1}^{2}$ and var$(\theta_{2}) = \sigma_{2}^{2}$.  Let $\theta_{3} = \alpha\theta_{1} + (1-\alpha)\theta_{2}$.
%
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,style=nextline,leftmargin=*, labelsep=\parindent,label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
\item Prove that $\theta_{3}$ is unbiased.
\item Assume that $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are statically independent, and find the measured squared error of $\theta_{3}$.
\item What choice of $\alpha$ minimizes the mean-squared error?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```